# ZF2 applications: best practice workflow for modules

Tags: git, svn, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am writing a ZF2 Application.  I started with ZendSkeletonApplication, and I will be adding some modules to it.  I may end up with tens of major modules in the application:

```
modules/
    Module1/
    Module2/
      ...
    ModuleN/
```

Question:  Do I keep a separate repository (and project) for each of the modules, or do I roll all of them up into a ball and store the root application and all of its modules in a single repository?

Bonus Question:  I am using git for source control.  If best practice is to use a single repository, will it make sense to use different branches for each of the modules, or just roll 'em up into a ball and commit with appropriate commit messages?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I keep a separate repository (and project) for each of the modules

Are you likely to want to reuse any of these modules in other applications (either now or in the future)? If yes, keep them in separate repos. Otherwise you may as well keep them in one.

If you end up keeping them separate, I'd recommend using Composer to manage these.

PS: By "I am using git for svn" I think you mean you're using git for source control. Git and Subversion are both pieces of software for source control.

Comment: thanks.  too bad there is not a single answer to this.  How about this:  I am creating a module for managing my userbase, logins, and ACL management.  In theory it is a reusable module, but it will contain my specific business logic, such as requirements specific to my business and probably not immediately reusable by someone outside of my company.  It sounds like keeping it a part of the repository will be fine.   But if I will keep it as a separate project, it will add complexity to managing my overall application.  Both have pros and cons, kind of a "catch 22" situation.

Answer (score 0):

A module is more focused on set of activities that are closely related and act on it's own, (less or no dependencies) on other modules. It would work nice if modules are kept in separate folders under modules folder (more specific to your application) or placed under vendor folder (general purpose or 3rd party modules).

If modules need changes you can overload the module by create new controllers or models by extending it in your application and add the specific changes.

Another advantage of ZF2 is the module structure is same as main application structure so it can be developed as separate application, and later integrated to any required projects